# Keeping track of scores in Java

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and I'm currently writing a program for an assignment that represents a 'sports league' (classes to represent player/club/match/league)

My main problems are occurring in the league class. Here are the relevant variables to give you an idea how I'm storing things:

```
public class League 
{
    private String leagueName;
    private ArrayList<Club> clubs;
    private ArrayList<Match> fixtures;
    private ArrayList<String> results2;
    private TreeMap<Match, String> results;
    private String topTeam;
    private String goldenBoot;

}
```

Currently trying to write a method in the League class which will print a 'league table' - i.e. a list of Clubs sorted by their points tally (held as variable in Club class) and I'm drawing a blank on it.

Further to this, I need to write two methods to find the top scorer (golden boot) and find the top team in the league; again I am drawing a blank. Perhaps I am overcomplicating things?

**Would be very grateful for suggestions/sample methods**

EDIT:

Ok, so that method I'm trying to write is something beginning with:

```
public void getLeagueTable() {
    for(Club c : clubs) {
        c.getTally();
    }
}
```

which would give the tally value for each Club object - but how to sort these results, and how to associate the highest with one Club is what's really troubling.

Comment: please post all the code, including the methods you are describing -- not just the class/variable declaration which you did

Comment: Remember that all class variables uinitialized are `null`s in Java. This is probably ok for `String`s but may be confusing for lists.

Comment: _urrently trying to write a method in the League class which will print a 'league table'_ , please post "that" method you are trying to write, and any issues you are facing

Answer (score 0):

To print the league table, you are going to need to sort the club array and then loop through each item and print the club name.

To sort the club array try using Collections.sort http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html

.. that is assuming you havent been told to implement your own algorithm

Again, more sorting required to get the top team and top scorer, then you will need to pick the top item from the sorted list.

Hope that helps...

Comment: Seems like this is what I need - but if I use Collections.sort on the Club array I will need to use a Comparator to ensure it sorts by the correct value (i.e. the result of returning getTally method in club class) - which begs the question 'how the heck do I do that!?'

Comment: Your club needs to implement comparable and override the compareto method to do that. Read the documentation for that one its all there :). Read this http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=10

Answer (score 0):

You better use `Set` rather than `ArrayList`. And here is a good start for your question :

```
void printLeagueTable(){

    i = 0 ;
    while( i != clubs.size() ){
         Club club = clubs.get(i);
         System.out.println("club: "+i+ "points: " club.points() );  
    }

}
```

Comment: That's certainly helpful, thanks. Although I'm unsure why to use a Set  instead?

Comment: In StackOverflow, rather than saying 'thank you' you **Vote-Up** http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up but Of course you need to have that privilege.